# Separating express queries from routes

Tags: javascript, api, express

I'm trying to make an express route that basically allows me to input an equity name as a query by putting `?symbol=` on the URL. After the equity name, I want to add a new route.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.get("/api/v1/equity/latest", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.query)
})

app.listen (3000, () => {
    console.log("listening to port 3000")
})
```

when I give then GET the URL as `localhost:3000/api/v1/equity?symbol=BBNI/latest/` and then look at the queries received, it received as `symbol = BBNI/latest/`

How do I separate the symbol query from the next `/latest` route?

Comment: *"and then look at the queries received"* What do you mean by that?

Comment: `localhost:3000/api/v1/equity?symbol=BBNI/latest/`, if I assume a `http://` or `https://` in front of it, is a request to `/api/v1/equity` on your server with the query string `?symbol=BBNI/latest/`. The route in your question won't receive that request, because it doesn't match the route you've shown (`/api/v1/equity/latest`). (It might match route handlers you haven't shown.) It would match `https://localhost:3000/api/v1/equity/latest?symbol=BBNI`, in which case the query string parameter `synbol` would have the value `"BBNI"`, but doesn't match what you listed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm sorry I'm very new to programming. What I mean is looking at the symbol object by doing the ```req.query.symbol```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder does that mean that all queries can only be done at the end of a URL link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird URL pattern, because if any dev sees this url:

```
/v1/equity?symbol=BBNI/latest/
```

It is implied that the `symbol` parameter *is* indeed `BBNI/latest/` and not just `BBNI`

However, if you want to 'separate' these parts, you can just do:

```
const [symbol, latest] = req.query.symbol.split('/', 2);
```

But you probably should design a better URL structure.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try to figure out a better URL structure.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good method.

Please try this.

```
const express = require("express")
const app = express()

app.get("/api/v1/equity/:symbol/latest", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.params.symbol)
})

app.listen (3000, () => {
    console.log("listening to port 3000")
})
```